# How to enable zend loader on xampp 1.7.4 with php.ini file

Tags: php, zend-loader

I'm trying to install zend guard loader run time on windows 7 OS, with XAMP-win32-1.7.4-VC9-installer, (with: php 5.3 and apache 2.0). we also
downloaded ZendGuardLoader-php-5.3-Windows and followed installation instruction by adding this line on our php.ini file under

```
zend_extension=<full_path_to_ZendLoader.dll>

zend_loader.enable = 1![enter image description here][1]
```

the real path is

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\ZendLoader.dll"
 zend_loader.enable = 1
```

however, after restarting xampp apache zend guard loader seems not to be loaded properly (see attached screen shots for your reference)

how can i solve it ?

thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

It may help :

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=43013

It seems that Zend can't run with PHP when PHP Thread Safety is enabled.

Comment: I am using php 5.6.24 with non thread safety and Xampp but still not able to load Zend  Loader. Can you please tell here how you did that?